# Kotlin with gradle build system cant add JRAW compile "net.dean.jraw:JRAW:1.1.0"

Tags: kotlin, gradle, reddit

I am all new to Kotlin and gradle and wanted to create a reddit scraper app for fun.
Cant get the guide from this page to work.

https://mattbdean.gitbooks.io/jraw/content/quickstart.html

The guide tells me to put this in the gradle file:

```
repositories {
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    compile "net.dean.jraw:JRAW:$jrawVersion"
}
```

But when i put that in my buid.gardle.kts file the ide reports an error

See image below of where the error occurs. The error message is Unexpected tokens.

[image: wat]

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer to my question, simply had to add in the variable in the gradle file...

```
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile

var jrawVersion = "1.1.0" //needed to add this in obviously

plugins {
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.4.21"
    application
}

group = "me.jeppe"
version = "1.0"

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    testImplementation(kotlin("test-junit"))
    compile ("net.dean.jraw:JRAW:$jrawVersion")
}

tasks.test {
    useJUnit()
}

tasks.withType<KotlinCompile>() {
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
}

application {
    mainClassName = "MainKt"
}
```